# Case insensitive pandas.concat

Tags: pandas

How would I perform a case insensitive pandas.concat?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3]},index=["a","b","c"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"b":[1,2,3]},index=["a","b","c"])
df1a = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3]},index=["A","B","C"])

pd.concat([df1, df2],axis=1)
   a  b
a  1  1
b  2  2
c  3  3
```

but this does not work:

```
pd.concat([df1, df1a],axis=1)

    a   A
A NaN   1
B NaN   2
C NaN   3
a   1 NaN
b   2 NaN
c   3 NaN
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

I have the same question for concat on a `Series`.

This works for a `DataFrame`:

```
pd.DataFrame([11,21,31],index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("A",x) for x in ["a","B","c"]])).rename(str.lower)
```

but this does not work for a `Series`:

```
pd.Series([11,21,31],index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("A",x) for x in ["a","B","c"]])).rename(str.lower)
TypeError: descriptor 'lower' requires a 'str' object but received a 'tuple'
```

For renaming, `DataFrames` use:

```
def rename_axis(self, mapper, axis=1):
        index = self.axes[axis]
        if isinstance(index, MultiIndex):
            new_axis = MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(mapper(y) for y in x) for x in index], names=index.names)
        else:
            new_axis = Index([mapper(x) for x in index], name=index.name)
```

whereas when renaming `Series`:

```
result.index = Index([mapper_f(x) for x in self.index], name=self.index.name)
```

so my updated question is how to perform the rename/case insensitive concat with a Series?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this via `rename`:

```
pd.concat([df1, df1a.rename(index=str.lower)], axis=1)
```

**EDIT**:

If you want to do this with a `MultiIndex`ed `Series` you'll need to set it manually, for now. There's [a bug report](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4605) over at pandas GitHub repo waiting to be fixed (thanks @ViktorKerkez).

```
s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(s.index.map(lambda x: tuple(map(str.lower, x))))
```

You can replace `str.lower` with whatever function you want to use to rename your `index`.

Note that you cannot use `reindex` in general here, because it tries to find values with the *renamed* index and thus it will return `nan` values, unless your `rename` results in no changes to the original `index`.

Comment: @PhillipCloud's code works perfectly fine. Can you explain a little bit better what are you trying to achieve? Update your question with the desired result.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez Question Updated. I added some clarification that PhillipCloud's answer works for DataFrames but not for Series.

Comment: One option would be to convert the Series to a DataFrame, rename the index and then convert back to a Series. This solution appears to work but is a bit clumsy.

Comment: Hmm yes, this is inconsistent behavior. `rename` on MultiIndexed series passes tuples to the rename mapper instead of strings. :-/ Maybe a bug?

Answer (score 1):

For the MultiIndexed Series objects, if this is not a bug, you can do:

```
s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
              s.index.map(lambda x: tuple(map(str.lower, x)))
          )
```

Comment: I do think that the behavior should be cleaned up such that calling s.rename on a MultiIndexed Series works the same as on a DataFrame.

Comment: I fully agree with you.

Comment: Definitely a bug with frames: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4160. Not sure about the `Series` case.

Comment: @PhillipCloud What exactly is the bug with DataFrames? DataFrames seem to work fine for me.

Comment: I meant to say that there *is* a bug with renaming `MultiIndex`ed frames. I'm not sure if it's related to the issue here though.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez See my edit above. You cannot use `reindex` here unless no changes are made to the index by the renaming operation.